# Flutter: Get the display name of a person other than the user currently logged into Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Apologies in advance if this has been asked and answered elsewhere. I have a Flutter project that uses Firebase for Authentication. I am searching for a way to get the display name of users other than the user who is currently logged in. I can't seem to find any resources on the topic.

For context user display names are stored while registering for the app using firebase auth. The display name of the user is specifically stored in the Firebase auth user table. I can retrieve the user name of the current logging user, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to retrieve the display name of a user other the one who is currently logged in.

The reason this is needed is to show the display name of the user who created a post/message. I have not posted any code for review as I have no idea where find the syntax i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not something you can query directly through Firebase auth. You would instead need to store this information elsewhere (like somewhere in Cloud Firestore) so that your clients can retrieve it. A common approach in Cloud Firestore would be to store the user's display name alongside the message as it's being posted. Then, when your app grabs a list of messages, they already have the name of the author along with the message content.

It just so happens the [Get to Know Firebase for Flutter codelab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter) does exactly that, so I might recommend going through the codelab if you want a more thorough explanation of how you would do this.